# Set time using hands on analog clock in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, clock, skiasharp

I'm trying to find a way to move the hands in an analog clock and get an hour or minute value from their position. There is time picker with clock similar to this, but timepicker uses one hand and opens dialog window.

The main questions is how to move hand with touch and how to get value from this.

I assume that I need to somehow connect the ondrag event and track in which coordinates the finger is.
and after the finger is released, I need to determine next to what hour or what minute the last coordinates were.

Maybe there is better way to draw analog clock so I can implement all this?

I am currently using SkiaSharp to draw a clock

```
<skia:SKCanvasView 
      x:Name="canvasView"  
      BackgroundColor="Transparent"
      PaintSurface="canvasView_PaintSurface"
      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 250, 250" />
```

```
SKPaint transparentFillPaint = new SKPaint
{
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
    Color = SKColors.Transparent
};

SKPaint whiteStrokePaint = new SKPaint
{
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
    Color = SKColors.White,
    StrokeWidth = 2,
    StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
    IsAntialias = true
};

SKPaint blueFillPaint = new SKPaint
{
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
    Color = new SKColor(187, 245, 247),
};

SKPaint backgroundFillPaint = new SKPaint
{
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
    Color = SKColors.Transparent
};

SKPath hourHandPath = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData(
    "M 0 -60 C 0 -55 0 -50 2.5 0 C 2.5 5 -2.5 5 -2.5 0 C 0 -50 0 -55 0 -60");
SKPath minuteHandPath = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData(
    "M 0 -80 C 0 -75 0 -70 2.5 0 C 2.5 5 -2.5 5 -2.5 0 C 0 -70 0 -75 0 -80");

public AnalogClockView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SetupCanvas();
}

protected void SetupCanvas()
{
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1f / 60), () =>
    {
        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        return true;
    });
}

private void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear();

    canvas.DrawPaint(backgroundFillPaint);

    int width = e.Info.Width;
    int height = e.Info.Height;

    // Set transforms
    canvas.Translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    canvas.Scale(Math.Min(width / 210f, height / 210f));

    // Get DateTime
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

    // Clock background
    canvas.DrawCircle(0, 0, 100, transparentFillPaint);

    // Hour and minute marks
    for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 6)
    {
        if (angle % 30 == 0)
        {
            var rect = new SKRect(0, -90, 6, -75);
            var r = new SKSize(6, 4);
            canvas.DrawRoundRect(rect, r, blueFillPaint);
        }

        canvas.RotateDegrees(6);
    }

    // Hour hand
    canvas.Save();
    canvas.RotateDegrees(30 * dateTime.Hour + dateTime.Minute / 2f);
    canvas.DrawPath(hourHandPath, blueFillPaint);
    canvas.Restore();

    // Minute hand
    canvas.Save();
    canvas.RotateDegrees(6 * dateTime.Minute + dateTime.Second / 10f);
    canvas.DrawPath(minuteHandPath, blueFillPaint);
    canvas.Restore();

    // Second hand
    canvas.Save();
    float seconds = dateTime.Second + dateTime.Millisecond / 1000f;
    canvas.RotateDegrees(6 * seconds);
    whiteStrokePaint.StrokeWidth = 2;
    canvas.DrawLine(0, 10, 0, -80, blueFillPaint);
    canvas.Restore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use BoxView to make analog clock, and you can use BoxView.GestureRecognizers to set time using hands.

```
 <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="absoluteLayout"
                SizeChanged="OnAbsoluteLayoutSizeChanged" >

    <BoxView x:Name="hourHand"
             Color="Black">
        <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated" />
        </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
    </BoxView>

    <BoxView x:Name="minuteHand"
             Color="Black" />

    <BoxView x:Name="secondHand"
             Color="Black" />
</AbsoluteLayout>


 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    // Structure for storing information about the three hands.
    struct HandParams
    {
        public HandParams(double width, double height, double offset) : this()
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            Offset = offset;
        }

        public double Width { private set; get; }   // fraction of radius
        public double Height { private set; get; }  // ditto
        public double Offset { private set; get; }  // relative to center pivot
    }

    static readonly HandParams secondParams = new HandParams(0.02, 1.1, 0.85);
    static readonly HandParams minuteParams = new HandParams(0.05, 0.8, 0.9);
    static readonly HandParams hourParams = new HandParams(0.125, 0.65, 0.9);

    BoxView[] tickMarks = new BoxView[60];

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create the tick marks (to be sized and positioned later).
        for (int i = 0; i < tickMarks.Length; i++)
        {
            tickMarks[i] = new BoxView { Color = Color.Black };
            absoluteLayout.Children.Add(tickMarks[i]);
        }

        //Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 60), OnTimerTick);
        OnTimerTick();
    }

    void OnAbsoluteLayoutSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Get the center and radius of the AbsoluteLayout.
        Point center = new Point(absoluteLayout.Width / 2, absoluteLayout.Height / 2);
        double radius = 0.45 * Math.Min(absoluteLayout.Width, absoluteLayout.Height);

        // Position, size, and rotate the 60 tick marks.
        for (int index = 0; index < tickMarks.Length; index++)
        {
            double size = radius / (index % 5 == 0 ? 15 : 30);
            double radians = index * 2 * Math.PI / tickMarks.Length;
            double x = center.X + radius * Math.Sin(radians) - size / 2;
            double y = center.Y - radius * Math.Cos(radians) - size / 2;
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(tickMarks[index], new Rectangle(x, y, size, size));
            tickMarks[index].Rotation = 180 * radians / Math.PI;
        }

        // Position and size the three hands.
        LayoutHand(secondHand, secondParams, center, radius);
        LayoutHand(minuteHand, minuteParams, center, radius);
        LayoutHand(hourHand, hourParams, center, radius);
    }

    void LayoutHand(BoxView boxView, HandParams handParams, Point center, double radius)
    {
        double width = handParams.Width * radius;
        double height = handParams.Height * radius;
        double offset = handParams.Offset;

        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(boxView,
            new Rectangle(center.X - 0.5 * width,
                          center.Y - offset * height,
                          width, height));

        // Set the AnchorY property for rotations.
        boxView.AnchorY = handParams.Offset;
    }

    bool OnTimerTick()
    {
        // Set rotation angles for hour and minute hands.
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        hourHand.Rotation = 30 * (dateTime.Hour % 12) + 0.5 * dateTime.Minute;
        minuteHand.Rotation = 6 * dateTime.Minute + 0.1 * dateTime.Second;

        // Do an animation for the second hand.
        double t = dateTime.Millisecond / 1000.0;

        if (t < 0.5)
        {
            t = 0.5 * Easing.SpringIn.Ease(t / 0.5);
        }
        else
        {
            t = 0.5 * (1 + Easing.SpringOut.Ease((t - 0.5) / 0.5));
        }

        secondHand.Rotation = 6 * (dateTime.Second + t);
        return true;
    }


    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {          
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        double r = hourHand.Rotation;
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Running:


                break;

            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                //set rotation according to TranslationX and TranslationY
                hourHand.Rotation = 180;

                break;
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the article about Adding a pan gesture recognizer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pan

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need. I still have a problem getting the angle of rotation. I use Atan2 to get the angle, but this does not work.
`angle = Math.Atan2 (e.TotalY - centerY, e.TotalX - centerX);`
Maybe I made a mistake with the center. I tried `absoluteLayout.Width / 2, absoluteLayout.Height / 2`, but the angle is always between 0 and 2.
I also tried your function `center.X - 0.5 * width;` and `center.Y - offset * height;` And the result is the same

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to calculate the angle with TotalX and TotalY from PanGesture

Comment: @ivsalti,may be, but you can specify how many degrees of rotation.